# Algorithm for finding least weight spanning tree of G that contains forest

Tags: algorithm, tree, breadth-first-search, kruskals-algorithm

I have a graph having the definition of G = (V;E) . This graph is a weighted undirected connected graph. F is a forest on the vertices V using edges in E.

So I need to have an algorithm to compute a least weight spanning tree of G that contains F. How can I do that ?

### My trying:

I am trying to apply BFS to find the connected component of the graph and then think to apply Prims or kruskal algorithm to find the minimum spanning tree.

But I could not relate my thinking to the above problems. How can I proceed to solve the above questions?

Comment: "a least weight spanning tree of G that contains F" does this mean that we only need just the individual minimum spanning trees and sum them :|

Comment: The proof for Kruskal's algorithm is a typical induction argument where the hypothesis with parameter t is that the decisions made by the greedy algorithm after t steps the partial solution extends to an optimal solution. This structure still works with a simple modification of Kruskal's.

Comment: how @David? can you put this as a answer?